# Is it safe to call WriteLineAsync again, before the previous Task is complete?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'd like to call `StreamWriter::WriteLineAsync()` on a file, *frequently*, without blocking. After some research, I find that `WriteLineAsync()` actually often performs synchronously, just buffering the data and returning a Completed Task. But occasionally it wont, and I understand there's lots of clever and not entirely deterministic optimisations to do with buffer sizes and flush intervals to deal with the vagaries of file systems. At this stage I don't know often I'll be filling that buffer, or whether there might other reasons `WriteLineAsync()` actually runs async, or whether switching .NET versions will change that.

So I'd like to be prepared up front. I figure I have two options:

1. If safe to do so, just call `WriteLineAsync()` as often as I like, potentially before the previous Task is complete. Then, if necessary, perhaps occasionally check for resource exhaustion somehow, and dial back my writing to accommodate.
2. If not, wrap my async method that calls `WriteLineAsync()` in a method that keeps a hold of the Task from the last time it was called, and throttles subsequent calls if the previous Task hasn't completed.

I suspect, given I can't see throngs of confused programmers who are crashing the system by smashing out `WriteLineAsync()` calls, that it's all magically taken care of. But I can't find any confirmation that is the case. So is it safe to call `WriteLineAsync()` repeatedly, without thought to the plight of the previous call?

Comment: Why would you want to call WriteLineAsync while a task from a previous call to the same function has not completed?

Comment: There is a [check internally](https://github.com/shekky/microsoft-dotnet-coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/StreamWriter.cs#L50) that will throw if an existing task is in progress, so you can't do this.

Comment: What you ask is a recipe for corruption. `StreamWriter` is used to write to text files. What would happen if a second operation started writing text at the same time as another? You'd end up with corrupted text.

Comment: Why not synchronously append your data to a list or queue, and provide an independent thread/task to pull data from that list and write it to the file as necessary, but from a single thread.

Comment: What is the *real* problem you want to solve? *Streams* buffer data, not just `StreamWriter`. So does the OS. That's not a problem. If you want a smaller or larger buffer you can configure it. Log libraries handle multithreaded logging by queueing operations, not trying to write everything at once. It's easy to do the same using, eg Channels or Dataflow blocks

Comment: I think the single answer to the previous 5 questions is that I was focused on the *buffer* part of `StreamWriter`, thinking I could pepper it with data from another (single) thread as soon as that data becomes available, and `StreamWriter` would buffer it all up sequentially and handle some periodic writing to disk. That's the real problem I'm solving, but the real result I'm looking for is enlightenment. And I think it comes in the form of the answer, which is that *even if* that's what `StreamWriter` is doing (and it may be), it will spit chips if you call it too often anyway, to be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.writelineasync) of the `StreamWriter.WriteLineAsync` method:

> **Exceptions**
>
> `ObjectDisposedException`
> The stream writer is disposed.
>
> `InvalidOperationException`
> The stream writer is currently in use by a previous write operation.

So apparently the answer is no. Starting a new asynchronous operation before a previous one has completed is an error.

Comment: OMG, I literally had that page open, to that section, while I was writing the question, because I figured that's where the answer would be, and I couldn't see it. Oh dear, thank you for pointing out what was right in front of me!

Comment: @HeathRaftery ha ha! Don't worry, It happens to all of us. :-) Your punishment now is that you have to explain to Panagiotis Kanavos your *real* problem. He always assumes that people post fake problems to StackOverflow, and you can make them spew the real problem if you pressure them enough. :-)